# Body is missing from request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a express app, and I'm using express-validator (https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator).

I'm using it as a middleware:

```
export default function verifyLogin(req, res, next) {
    req.checkBody({
        'email': {
            notEmpty: true,
            isEmail: {
                errorMessage: 'Invalid Email'
            },
            errorMessage: "Empty"
        },
        'password': {
            notEmpty: true,
            errorMessage: 'Empty',
            "isLength": {
                options: [{min: 5, max: 20}],
                errorMessage: "Password must be between 5 and 20 chars long"
            }
        }
    });

    req.getValidationResult().then(result => {
        if(!result.isEmpty()) {
            res.send(result.array());
            console.log('In here, wrong params');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
}
```

But if I change `res.send(result.array());` to `res.status(422).send(result.array());` the body of the request is missing if I log it at the first line after the function (before I use `req.CheckBody`).

I'm total clueless of the behaviour. Any clues?

Added:
I get a empty body if I send a post request from angular and using `res.status().send,` but not from postman. 
If I use `res.send()` - both postman and angular works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that content-type was not specified in the angular2 app.

For some reason, when using res.status(), the content-type needed to be specified, but not when res.send() was used.